# Actionscript 3.0: How to communicate between main window and popup window untill main window gets server login response

Tags: authentication, actionscript-3, popup

We are working in a project where we are designing the GUI in action script 3.0.

The login screen will do a http call with the opensso server for autherntication and if the login fails, the error popup window should be displayed.

Now the problem is that sometimes the authentication takes a long time and the end user doesn't know the situation. So he is clicking the **LOGIN** button once again. So the client wants another popup window which should display only **WAIT** till the server sends the login response.

This is our ssoAuthenticate method  -

```
private function ssoAuthenticate():void
{
    var loaderUrl:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.loaderInfo.url;
    var myLoadBaseUrl:LoadBaseUrl = new LoadBaseUrl();
    var ssoBaseUrl:String = myLoadBaseUrl.getSSOUrl();
        
    var url:String = ssoBaseUrl.concat("opensso/json/authenticate");
    var srv:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
    srv.url = url;
    srv.method = "POST";
    srv.contentType = "application/json";
    srv.headers ={
        "X-OpenAM-Username": userName,
        "X-OpenAM-Password": password,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    var data:Object = new Object();
    srv.resultFormat = "e4x";
    srv.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, authenticateSuccess);
    srv.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, authenticateFailed);         
    srv.send("{}");
}
```

How we can make it happen? How we can introduce another WAIT popup in this code? And that popup window should disappear whenever the event **ResultEvent.RESULT** comes back from the server.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The **LocalConnection** class is designed exactly for that one purpose: to allow several SWF application running on the same device communicate: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your user click on the login button call `login.removeEventListerner(MouseEvent.CLICK,ssoAuthenticate)` until **ResultEvent.RESULT** comes back from your server
also for better UX you are able to show a loader movieclip or progress dialog like this
https://docs.airnativeextensions.com/docs/dialog/progress-dialog